# Verificar se um username já existe no banco de dados angular 2 + php

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Preciso verificar se um usuário já existe antes de registrar.

Tenho os seguintes métodos:

register.component.ts:

```
import { AlertService } from './../alert.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent{
  model: any = {};
  loading = false;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private userService: UserService,
              private alertService: AlertService) { }


  register(){
    this.loading = true;

    this.userService.create(this.model)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
            this.alertService.success('Registro realizado com sucesso!', true);
        },
        error => {
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }

}
```

Meu método no user service:

```
create(user: Usuario) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/api.php', JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

Minha api:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,'mydb');


$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true); 
if(isset($user['username'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username,password)
VALUES ('".$user['firstName']."', '".$user['lastName']."', '".$user['username']."','".$user['password']."')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'sucess'));die;


}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Coloquei no bd o username como unique achando que retornaria algum erro, mas ainda falta algo na minha implementação. Como e onde devo verificar se o username já existe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que fazer um SELECT no banco para verificar se o username existe, se não existir faz INSERT

```
$username=$user['username'];

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

$row = $result->fetch_row();

if ($row[0] > 0) {
    //já existe
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username,password)
    VALUES ('".$user['firstName']."', '".$user['lastName']."', '".$user['username']."','".$user['password']."')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'sucess'));die;
}
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações mas agora retorna no meu console: "Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://localhost/api/api.php. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente)."

Eu já possuo no meu header:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Disso eu não entendo, porém tem algo aqui na resposta do Marcelo nesse post https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-requisicao-cross-origin-bloqueada-36630

Comment: Você também pode pesquisar aqui nessa página por `Requisição cross-origin bloqueada` que deve encontrar alguma solução para seu caso